# Ajax json_encode error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" when returning array with keys

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Chrome console shows error when I send json_encode from php with defined keys, but works when I do not define keys:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

This PHP ajax_return_array.php code works:

```
 $array = array("a","b","c","d");
 echo json_encode( $array );
```

This PHP ajax_return_array.php code fails:

```
 $array = array(1=>"a",2=>"b",3=>"c",4=>"d");
 echo json_encode( $array );
```

jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_return_array.php",
    success: function(result) {
        if(result) {
            resultObj = eval (result);
            alert( resultObj );
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
});
```

This is the json data causing the error:
{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c","4":"d"}

Comment: show the ajax for `jax_return_array.php` the one you posted is for `ajax_return_array.php`

Comment: Your json data is valid....why you are using `eval`??

Comment: The eval is just to output to the alert dialog.

Comment: `eval()` is evil. Use the safer `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Or set `dataType: 'json'`. If your json really is invalid that would cause the script to go to the ajax error handler.

Comment: So eval was throwing the error. I understand now and will not use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's ajax function should automatically parse the response into an object. Just remove your `eval` statement and assign the response to your resultObj. Also, since you're not posting anything, it should probably be a "GET", which is defaulted. (Don't forget to change your php code too).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_return_array.php",
    success: function(result) {
        if(result) {
            resultObj = result;
            alert( resultObj );
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
});
```